# Does Firebase ML kit supports QR Code generator?

Tags: android, firebase, google-mlkit

I need to implement a QR code generator from my app. Will the firebase ML kit provides such a feature to generate QR Code from a string? or I need to go with some alternative libraries like zXing?

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't generate QR codes.  But it will [scan them](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning).